# How do my questions IMMEDIATELY get more than "1 view"?

Tags: discussion, views

I don't think that users are just frantically hitting refresh on the Questions page so that each new question that pops up gets their attention as soon as it gets posted. I mean it's a good thing, but how?

edit: boom! 3 views already in less than a minute.

Comment: Magic and Unicorns.

Comment: We have *many* users. Some of us are also frantically hitting the Refresh button, to be honest.

Comment: ok, 2 comments in less than a minute. That explains it. Thanks.

Comment: 2 comments, one comment upvote, 6 views and an edit in 2 minutes :-).

Comment: Do you mean on SO? I don't remember the exact data, but the number of visits/day is just ***huge***. I'm not surprised that someone arrives/visits the main stream of question just when you ask it.

Comment: The websocket-based new-question notifications do allow for fast responses these days. No need for constant refreshing!

Comment: @Martijn, I tried to convince my muscle memory about that, only with mixed results.

Comment: Er, how is "IMMEDIATELY" the same as "3 views already in less than a minute"?

Comment: @Alenanno, [see here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't resist but take a screenshot of this. It seems they do genuinely start off with just your own view (a total of 1).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you used the `new questions` web-socket-powered live update feature, you *always* get a '1 view' counter.